# this Keyword and static Methods - Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

The `this` keyword cannot be used in static methods. I am using static methods by design but also need to pop up a window with the method. Here is the code I have. I observed the `createPopUp` method of `PopUpManager` class and it needs a `DisplayObject` as a first argument. `this` is the `DisplayObject` but I did not get what is `DisplayObject` at that point. So how can I replace `this` to corresponding/correct `DisplayObject`?

---

```
public static function UniteDetayPopup(f:Function):void
{
    var uniteler:UniteDetay = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, UniteDetay, true) as UniteDetay;
    PopUpManager.centerPopUp(uniteler);
}
```

---

edit:

it is in a TitleWindow component and it pops up with other component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just pass `Application` instance to this method.

```
var uniteler:UniteDetay = PopUpManager.createPopUp(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as DisplayObject, UniteDetay, true) as UniteDetay;
```

Comment: I created a DisplayObject variable, assigned the value (just for a shorter parenthesis) , and it works like a charm. Thanks!